# Configure Cron to mail the weekly output of "last" command

Tags: centos

I need to schedule a weekly report that will run every Sunday at 10:00 PM that will show all accounts (usernames and IP addresses) that have logged into the server.
This output would be sent to the email.

I would like to make use of "last" & "mail" commands for this purpose.

The cron would look something like the below but the '**-a**' option will list the entire logged in users info. Whereas, I'm looking for the users info who have logged in the previous week only. How this can be achieved?

```
0 22 * * 0 /usr/bin/last -a | mail -s "SSH Logins Report" -r user@domain.com
```

**Server Info**

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5

Kernel: 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64

Comment: Care to give some more info? What is this "last" command? Is this "report" some kind of script/program?

Comment: "last" is a built-in command.

/usr/bin/last - Shows the listing of all the last logged in users on a linux machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `utmpdump` command for that, as it has Year in it's output

```
for weekday in 'monday' 'tuesday' 'wednesday' 'thursday' 'friday' 'saturday' 'sunday' ;
do
    /usr/bin/utmpdump /var/log/wtmp | grep "`date --date \"$weekday week ago\" '+%a %b %d\s[^ ]*\s%Y'`" 
done 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST_OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/last.txt
last -a > ${LAST_OUTPUT_FILE}
OUTPUT_FILE=/tmp/out.txt
> ${OUTPUT_FILE}

for i in {1..6}
do
        DATE_TO_SEARCH=$(date -d"-${i}days" "+%b %d" | sed  "s/.\([1-9]\)/ \1/")
        grep "${DATE_TO_SEARCH}" ${LAST_OUTPUT_FILE} >> ${OUTPUT_FILE}
done
mail -s "SSH Logins Report" -r user@domain.com < ${OUTPUT_FILE}
echo "Output File : ${OUTPUT_FILE}"
echo "Last File extract : ${LAST_OUTPUT_FILE}"
```

Comment: there is no Year in output of last. So it will show outputs of any year with the same date.

Comment: yes.. thats true